# How do I go pearl farming?

Tags: story-of-seasons

So the in-game farm guides suggest that you can use the Fish Hatchery to farm pearls. Can any oyster or clam work? How do I get the pearl from oyster or clam once I raise some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy pearl oysters from Sakura Country after you harvest a total of 30 fish/clams from fish hatcheries.

It takes around 15 days for an oyster to produce a single pearl, and it will be a random color.

You can also collect various pearls from diving in Eda's portion of the river, and buy yellow pearls in the antique shop.